# Level of Agree-ness in ensemble models

Tags: classification, model-evaluation, ensemble-learning, multi-class

I am trying to analyze the output of multiple models (as in ensemble method), classifying a *multiclass* dataset. I would like to study the behavior of the models compared to each other when they are classifying/miscalassifying. For instance I want to check at the misclassified instances, how different models have contributed to the final label: if all the models agreed upon the wrong label, or if some models have disagreed, etc. (I can think of the english word **solidarity** of the models but I am not sure if it's a good word for such concept). Is there any established systematic study for such issue? something as structured as confusion matrices.

One inference from such results is that for example I can see if single models add any value to my machine. If all of the models do the same voting pattern and making the same mistake, then it's better if I remove all but only 1.

Of course I can design an ad-hoc scenario for my research to answer these questions, but I was wondering if there is already any related subject in the literature that I have missed.

Comment: I guess this line of reasoning only holds for Bagging methods like Random Forest? It seems you are examining the overall behavior of models. If one single CART acts exactly the same as the a forest, of course the simpler one is kept. And if that is the case, why a complex ensemble at first?

Comment: @doubllle That's 100% right. But I want to go further than that with the reasonings. for example I check how the models agree upon each classes. something like a 'colaborative confusion matrix'! my project is a medical project and I should provide the solutions as interpretable as possible, report the uncertainties and points of failure and so on.